# Create input on button clicked with angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am building a website and I need to create inputs dynamically. I currently have a button and it is pressed by the user, a text input is created with an appropriate span that I set (using the class, ids, style and all that) and add it to a div (lets say a list of input(s) in same div).

Now I want to do it with AngularJS.
Can someone show me example of code that creates the input dynamically?

Here is the start:

```
    <script></script>
<div id="AddBtn" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 0px; background-color: #982222; color: #fff; font-size: 18px;" onclick="AddRowExample()">Add +</div>
<div id="listExample">

</div>
```

I want learn the how to do it the `angular` way. I already tried to create the input dynamically but it doesn't work. I seem to be getting `$compile` is not defined. I tried to figure out how to inject the `$compile` service but it didn't work.

After Edit:

Here is the code in my system:
js:

```
function getDefaultAmount(lines_number){
var defaultAmount = document.createElement("div");
defaultAmount.id = "AmountValue_" + lines_number;
defaultAmount.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock amountValueStyle");
defaultAmount.setAttribute("ng-app", "myApp");
defaultAmount.setAttribute("ng-controller", "myCtrl");

var amountInput = document.createElement("input");
amountInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
amountInput.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock");
amountInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "???? ????");
amountInput.setAttribute("ng-model", "firstName");
defaultAmount.appendChild(amountInput);

var amountVal = document.createElement("div");
amountVal.id = "AmountVal_" + lines_number;
amountVal.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock");
amountVal.setAttribute("ng-bind", "{firstName}");
defaultAmount.appendChild(amountVal);



return defaultAmount.outerHTML;

}
```

and here is the function that called to ^:

```
    function createNewRow(line_number){
    var lines_number = line_number;
    var lines_place = document.getElementById("EditLinesPlace");
    if (lines_number < 19) {
        //-----Start build line elements
        //Create the line
        var line = document.createElement("div");
        line.id = "Line_" + lines_number;
        line.style.cssText = "border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;";
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "lineNum width100 padding2_0 inlineBlock";                          
        line.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        lines_place.appendChild(line);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //Create the category place in the line
        var category = document.createElement("div");
        category.id = "Category_" + lines_number;
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "categoryStyle";                          
        category.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        category.innerHTML = '<div class="categoryBtn" onclick="openPopup(window.current_category,window.actions_list[0],'+ lines_number +');">' + "??? ???????" + '</div>' + getDefaultCategory(lines_number);
        line.appendChild(category);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //Create the date place in the line
        var date = document.createElement("div");
        date.id = "Date_" + lines_number;
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "dateStyle";                          
        date.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        date.innerHTML = "?????: " + getDate(lines_number);
        line.appendChild(date);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //Create the amount place in the line
        var amount = document.createElement("div");
        amount.id = "Amount_" + lines_number;
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "amountStyle";                          
        amount.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        amount.innerHTML = '<span class="inlineBlock">' +"???? :"+ '</span>' + getDefaultAmount(lines_number);
        $compile(amount)($scope);

        line.appendChild(amount);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //Create the repeated place in the line
        var repeated = document.createElement("div");
        repeated.id = "Repeated_" + lines_number;
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "repeatedStyle";                          
        repeated.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        repeated.innerHTML = '<div class="repeatedBtn" onclick="updateRepeated(' + lines_number + ')">' + '<span class="floatA">???????? : ' + getDefaultRepeated(lines_number) + '</span></div>';
        line.appendChild(repeated);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //Create the note place in the line
        var note = document.createElement("div");
        note.id = "Note_" + lines_number;
        var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        addClass.value = "noteStyle";                          
        note.setAttributeNode(addClass);
        note.innerHTML = "????? : " + getDefaultNote(lines_number);
        line.appendChild(note);
        /*//Create break line*/
        //-----End build line elements

        window.line_number++;

    }
    else {
        var error = document.getElementById("ErrorPlace");
        error.innerHTML = '<div class="" style="">???? ?????? ???????? ??? 20</div>';
        return window.line_number;
    }
}
```

This gives me `$compile` is undefined.

Comment: so, show what you try

Comment: Maybe you don't need to create an input element, perhaps you can have it there already but have it hidden with ng-show or ng-hide, and then show it up when you need to. Its not an answer to what you want, but a work around.

Comment: you can use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) - this directive add element to dom if condition true, and not add if - false. Or use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) if you want add it few times

Comment: this is in my system...but the example that i want is more simple ..=]

Comment: also provide sample output which you expect. and also you can provide sample that you have without angular

Comment: oh, seems like you just need move html that you need in some template and use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive

Comment: can you provide sample output html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could ng-repeat your inputs, and then just add another item to that model you're repeating

http://plnkr.co/edit/TXZNcq?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [0];
    $scope.moreInputs = function(){
      console.log('added an input');
      $scope.inputs.push(0);
    };
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="moreInputs();">+ input</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i sure input would be bind with some ng-model, so better use object instead simple `0` in input array

Comment: @Grundy is right, my example was just to demonstrate it in the simplest way. When you implement it for real, should use the actual model that also tracks the data for the inputs

Comment: the example is realy good! ty!
how i can add id and class to the input?

Comment: if you just add the class inside of the ng-repeat like `<input type="text" class="foo">` it will be there. If you want each one to be different you can even do something like
```
<div ng-repeat="(key, input) in inputs track by $index">
      <input type="text" class="foo-{{key}}">
</div>
```

Comment: well i have a variable in js that tell me how mach lines the user is open...
the var name is window.lines_number.
now i have that code:
<div id="Line_1" style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);" class="lineNum width100 padding2_0 inlineBlock">
            </div>

as you can see the id is uniq and its need to get the number from the javascript var(window.lines_number), how can i do that?

i use this var for alot of things in my website system so i dont want to change all now..

Comment: I guess if you want to keep that you could always just bind it to an angular scope var in your controller like `$scope.lineNumber = window.lines_number`